# .Net Maui a picker with multiple selection?

Tags: maui

Is there in MAUI a picker with multiple selection ? I couldn't find any.

So far, am using the standard one. but it doesn't have the ability to select multiple values.

```
<Picker x:Name="MyPicker" VerticalOptions="Center"></Picker>
```

In the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/picker) neither, they don't talk about any multiple selection.

Comment: use a CollectionView

Comment: If you need this multi-selector to "pop up", put that CollectionView inside a [Maui CT Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup).

Answer (score 3):

In .NET MAUI, you can use the `MultiSelectCollectionView` control to provide a picker with multiple selection capabilities. The `MultiSelectCollectionView` control allows users to select multiple items from a collection.

Install the `Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility` package from NuGet.

And in the xaml file add the namespace for the newly added nuget & use the `MultiSelectCollectionView` as:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNamespace"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<controls:MultiSelectCollectionView
    x:Name="multiSelectCollectionView"
    SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <controls:MultiSelectCollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Option 1</x:String>   // Sample Array
            <x:String>Option 2</x:String>
            <x:String>Option 3</x:String>
            <x:String>Option 4</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </controls:MultiSelectCollectionView.ItemsSource>
</controls:MultiSelectCollectionView>
```

And in the code behind you can access it as:

```
var selectedItems = multiSelectCollectionView.SelectedItems.Cast<string>().ToList();
```